# Cartoon series. Man with four fingers in a team with a dinosaur

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a cartoon from the 90s or 00s about a synthetic guy with 4 fingers who is in a team with a blonde and a dinosaur with guns. That guy is also some kind of weapon.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Please try to add more details to this question. As it stands it is a bit vague and hard to answer.

Comment: Sounds vaguely like the herculoids, but that is a much older cartoon.  They did have dinosaurs, the girl was blonde though and at least one of the critters fired "bullets" out of its "horn".

Answer (score 2):

"Project G.e.e.K.e.R."(1997 TV series)?

The main character was synthetic and was in a team with a blonde and a gun toting dinosaur voiced by Brad Garrett. He also had four fingers, but that's true of many cartoon characters. You can watch some of the 13 episodes on Youtube, but I posted one below.

Comment: Is it just me or does that 4 fingered guy sound like Fry?